# CSS Flexbox width widthout overflow 100%

Tags: css, flexbox

I have two problems:

1.) How do I get the yellow box to not be wider than the parent flexbox even with long words. With "Calc" it would work, but that seems unsafe to me. Is there another solution that the width is automatically?

2.) What is the safest way to make the entered text wrap?

```
---
<style>
.container {
  width: 300px;
  background-color:#0f0;
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  width:200px;
  background-color:#f00;
}
.right {
  width:100%;
  background-color:#ff0;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    Container 300px
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    This text.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    This is a prettyveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylong word. 
  </div>
</div>
---
```

[screenshot of html result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmLEv.png)

Comment: Use "word-break: break-word;" to wrap the text.
Once you wrap the text, the yellow box will fit in the container.

Comment: min-width:0 to yellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<style>
.container {
  width: 300px;
  background-color:#0f0;
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  width:200px;
  background-color:#f00;
}
.right {
  flex: 1;
  word-break: break-word;
  background-color:#ff0;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    Container 300px
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    This text.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    This is a prettyveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylong word. 
  </div>
</div>
```